# Docker и PostgresSQL: Connection to localhost:5432 refused

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, docker, spring-boot

У меня есть `Spring MVC` приложение, которое я хочу добавить в `Docker`. Я успешно создал образ и настроил `Docker`, но при запуске у меня выдается ошибка от `PostgresSQL`.

```java
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:303) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:57) ~[flyway-core-7.1.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:69) ~[flyway-core-7.1.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:475) ~[flyway-core-7.1.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:164) ~[flyway-core-7.1.1.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1161) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar!/:2.4.0]
        at ru.coffeetearea.CoffeeTeArea.main(CoffeeTeArea.java:12) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar!/:42.2.18]
        ... 45 common frames omitted
```

Для решения этой проблемы я пробовал разные варианты:

1. Менял `localhost` на `db` название: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/coffeetearea`.
2. Пытался запустить с другим портом.
3. Отдельно указывал `server.post = 5432`.

Ни один из вариантов не сработал. Что можно предпринять?

P.S. Проект собран: `Spring boot`, `Hibernate`, `PostgresSQL`

Dockerfile:

```java
FROM openjdk:11
ADD build/libs/Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 5432:5432
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "Coffeetearea-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

application.properties:

```java
#Databse
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/coffeetearea
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=barca3508
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

Comment: а у вас postgres в докере запушен? и почему у вас в java приложение выставляется порт 5432? это же порт для postgres, очень похоже на то, что приложение запустили, а postgres нет, вот и ошибка, ну и вместо localhost:5432 скорее всего дожно быть имя контейнера с базой

Comment: @ExplodingKitten, а не поможет по идее имя контейнера с базой, ибо `docker-composer` нету, а значит и дефолтного бриджа меж контейнерами тоже.

Comment: @icYFTL никто не мешает создать user network руками и все будет работать, но мне пока кажется, что у человека просто контейнер с базой не запущен?  а кидать все контейнеры на host network я считаю не совсем правильным

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае мне помогли следующие настройки `Docker.file` и `Dockerfile.postgres`:

1. Создаем ***Docker.file*** в папке с проектом:

```java
FROM openjdk:11
ADD build/libs/yourJar.jar yourJar.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "yourJar.jar"]
```

2. Создаем ***Dockerfile.postgres***:

```java
FROM postgres:12
COPY init-scripts/test.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sql
EXPOSE 5432
```

3. Создаем ***DockerCompose.yml***:

```java
version: '3.1'
services:
  app:
    container_name: springboot-postgresql
    image: springboot-app
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgresqldb
  postgresqldb:
    image: postgres
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*********YOUR PASSWORD
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
```

Если описывать ситуацию кратко, мне не хватило файла `Dockerfile.postgres`, а так же не было верных конфигураций в `DockerCompose.yml`. Меняете на свои порты и данные, должно заработать.

Comment: т.е. процесс postgres-а у вас просто вообще не запускался?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да. На начальном этапе не знал, что нужно создавать и для postgres'а конфиги и настройки, так как думал, что в образе моего приложения эта инфа уже будет храниться, и он без труда будет ориентироваться. Оказалось, что все работает не так.

Answer (score 0):

Как небольшой костыль могу предложить попробовать добавить флаг `--network="host"` в запуск контейнера.
То-есть: `docker run <name> -itd --network="host"`

И да я тоже сначала не понял почему порт приложения `5432`.
Выставите другой порт, а иначе будут конфликты с `postgresql`